# SQL Server - Dynamic number of columns in Insert statement

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I will not go into the reasons for this requirement (too long and not relevant).

I have a rather wide table `Table_1` with 256 columns, all `NVARCHAR(512)` and accepting null.

On the other hand, I have a string into which a dynamic select is built and, depending on the case, it generates each time a different number of columns.

The results of the query need to be inserted into the `Table_1`.

The problem is that either I explicitly mention the columns into which results are to be inserted or the results of the query must match the structure of the target table.

For instance, let's have:

```
DECLARE @Table_1 TABLE (Field_1 NVARCHAR(512) ,
                        Field_2 NVARCHAR(512) ,
                        Field_3 NVARCHAR(512) ,
                        Field_4 NVARCHAR(512) ,
                        Field_5 NVARCHAR(512) ,
                        Field_6 NVARCHAR(512)   ) ;
```

And a query like:

```
DECLARE @_My_Query NVARCHAR(1000) = '
SELECT Name    Field_1 ,
       Street  Field_2 ,
       Phone   Field_3
 FROM My_Table 
 ';
```

Now, I can't do:

```
INSERT INTO @Table_1 
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @_My_Query ;
```

because it would complain about mismatching columns. Neither can I hardcode `(Field_1,Field_2,Field_3)` because other queries would need a different number of columns.

### Edit

Answers to the comments posted by KrazzyNefarious, Jeroen Mostert and  Damien_The_Unbeliever:

I do have a clear view of the fields returned by the query as well as their count.

The functionality I'm trying to implement is as follows:

1. The system I'm working on should support the generation of CSV files with a variable number of columns and contents.
2. The idea is that the query that generates the result data is prepared at a higher layer and sent to a Stored Procedure (as a string) along with a table that describes all the columns of the result (e.g. ordinal position, field name, data type, title in the Excel's first row, etc.).
3. The Procedure I'm working on would take the query string and run a combined `INSERT INTO Table_1 EXECUTE sp_executesql @_My_Query`. Once this is done, the mechanism that examines each and every field (for instance, to add `"` whenever needed) can handle the contents of Table_1 without any concern about the origin of the data.

I would prefer to avoid using temporary tables since, besides the ugliness of the approach, it affects performance and additional issues (need to delete records after use, collisions, etc.).

Comment: what is the maximum number of columns that the dynamic query may return?

Comment: How do you know how to map fields? Are the names at least in correspondence?

Comment: "... I have a string into which a dynamic select is built and ..." - are you able to make changes to *the process of constructing that string*, such that you can track how many columns have been added? Starting from just a string containing query text and trying to parse it to determine the column count seems like too much complexity here.

Comment: describe the issue. this looks like a solution you (or someone else) found and are now trying to implement. how the select is generated? you have control on the creation of the dynamic select? what's the requirement behind a dynamic select to insert into a bunch of nullable columns?

Comment: @KrazzyNefarious, please see the EDIT.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, please see the EDIT.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, please see the EDIT.

Comment: @Paolo, please see the EDIT.

Comment: A bit of a hacky way but you should be able to get what you want with `SELECT INTO #Table FROM OPENQUERY`. Assuming your question is to create a table with unknown columns.

Comment: Hi FDavidov. Please ping me if you want to roll back my edits - I can assure you with some confidence that the community broadly support them. The two edits here are (1) chatty material, such as appreciations or the scale of appreciations, tend to be exercised, since we prefer technical writing and brevity; (2) edit titles are best as headings rather than merely being bolded, since they are a declaration of a whole section rather than some words needing spoken emphasis.

Comment: @halfer, **thanks** for your comments. Unfortunately (or, perhaps, not), I was educated to be respectful, cordial and thankful (among other things), and that was too long ago to change now. I quite disagree with any attempt to standardize the way people express since, as you may have noticed already, none of us is a machine (or, at least, not me). There are many questions posted in this forum which are not readable at all (poor English command at the author's side) and they are far more time consuming for the reader than my "thanks" part. Bottom line: I quite like my phrasings. Cheers!!

Comment: I understand that view, FDavidov, and you are not the first person to express it. Thanks for your thoughts. The canonical advice [is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/472495). Do please try to take the community consensus into account. A good rule of thumb is "we're closer to Wikipedia than a chatroom". The authors of encyclopaedia articles were surely taught to be polite, but they do not add thanks at the end of their material.

Comment: (I believe there is some Stack Overflow Inc. endorsement of brevity as well, in the Help Centre - something like "get the answers you want without chit-chat").

Comment: @halfer, of course I'm in favor of brevity. Still, imagine this post construct: "__I want to do **this**. Tried **that**. It didn't work. Suggestions?__". In many cultures (mine included), it would be considered as **VERY RUDE phrasing** and hence I would not even try to assist. It is a good idea to set a basic standard, but it is not a good idea to ignore the fact that we are dealing with people coming from many different cultures. As such, some **flexibility** should be exercised. Finally, I think that the reviewing process should be focused mainly on clarity of the question.

Comment: Sure, brevity can be taken too far, I agree. I personally find one-word questions rather lazy and overly-entitled (but then a good chunk of Stack Overflow users who write in that way are probably reflecting their intrinsic entitlement - and they will often get short shrift). However, asking for "suggestions" or "help" or "assistance" is considered [not really a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Thus, if you are looking for a question to finish on, make it the actual thing you want to determine - "is there a succinct way to set up a dynamic number of columns in SQL Server?" is excellent. It is neither entitled or chatty. Of course, if you have that question in your title then it may be unnecessary from a repetition perspective, in which case "Is there a better way of doing this?" might be fine.

Comment: Incidentally, I am most happy to continue this discussion - I find the interaction effects of our conscious and subconscious cultural attitudes to be most intriguing. However, if you are keen for cultural change _here_, then I would suggest laying out your thoughts on the _Meta_ site. I believe I have set out the current community position, and thus it is not me that you need to persuade. Stack Overflow Inc recently blogged about this, and they hinted that perhaps the technical writing requirement might be up for discussion - so lobbying in this direction might not be a waste of (your) time.

Comment: For interest: [my discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) about confidence is also about brevity - and ponders whether "polite" material can be interpreted as begging and pleading in disguise.

Comment: @halfer, I will certainly check it out (your discussion as well as the forum). I find it worth noting also that my command of English is not as rich and articulated as yours and, as a result, I might need more words than you to say the same. Last, I also enjoy having discussions with people that know how to express, like yourself. Cheers!!!!

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate the exchange also `:-)`.

Answer (score -1):

This:

*The system I'm working on should support the generation of CSV files with a variable number of columns and contents.*

is the crux of your problem. You have chosen a path that doesn't really match/support this requirement. You have ruled out temp tables. So the only other option is to create a (temp or permanent) table for each export "situation" - which is ugly and prone to lots of other issues. Because a table in a rdbms has a fixed structure. More than just a different number of columns, you also need to consider different datatypes. Are you ignoring that issue as well or did you make a very simplifying assumption? If you only look at one situation you often lose sight of the complexity you face.

In addition, you can search for the many discussions about exporting CSV data from a stored procedure (or script). It is simply a nest of problems and constraints even without the variability of the source data structure.

I suggest you are using the wrong tool to implement your requirement. TSQL is simply not intended and does not really support ETL. If you intend to go down this path, you will need some advanced skills.

Comment: Thank you @Smor for your post, though I can't really see in which way it is of any help. Some comments: (1) It would be more useful if you assume that whoever posts a question may have at least some basic understanding of what he/she is talking about (not always true, but good as a starting point). (2) It would appear reasonable to assess that there will be thousands of different results structures and many users concurrently, making the option of temp or permanent table prone to collisions, load => irrelevant. (3) Advanced Skills: Well, I think I found a solution. Will post it and you judge.